# How can I change "Your order" text on checkout page in WooCommerce under certain conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

With this code I can change "Your Order" text in checkout page. But I need to change if specific product in my cart or virtual product is in my cart.

```php
function custom_wc_translations($translated){
    $text = array(
    'Your order' => 'Your new phrase',
    'any other string' => 'New string',
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
    return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_wc_translations', 20 );
```

I found this code but for different place for specific product. how can I change it?

```php
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_conditionally_order_review_heading_text', 10, 3 );
function change_conditionally_order_review_heading_text( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    if( $text === 'Your Order' && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ){
        // HERE set the desired specific product ID
        $targeted_product_id = 1122;

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $targeted_product_id == $cart_item['data']->get_id() )
                return __( 'İletişim Bilgileri', $domain );
        }
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text you want to change is located in [`checkout/form-checkout.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/1c4f02d2e2da598d202911acec0847fb26ae172a/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php) line [54](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/1c4f02d2e2da598d202911acec0847fb26ae172a/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php#L54)

```php
<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

As you will see there are just before and after the

- `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading` and
- `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` hooks, only these do not apply to the `H3` tag

So `gettext` is recommended if you don't want to overwrite the template file.

To debug this and other text you can use

```php
function filter_gettext( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r( $text , 1 ), '</pre>';
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext',  'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```

---

So to answer your question, this should suffice

- Check for a specific product ID

```php
function filter_gettext( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    if( $text == 'Your order' && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {        
        // HERE set the desired specific product ID
        $targeted_product_id = 1122;

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $targeted_product_id == $cart_item['data']->get_id() ) {
                $translated = __( 'İletişim Bilgileri', $domain );
            }
        }
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext',  'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```

---

**UPDATE 10/2020**

- You can use the following code to check for multiple product IDs

```php
function filter_gettext( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    if( $text == 'Your order' && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {        
        // HERE set the desired specific product IDs
        $targeted_product_ids = array( 1122, 30, 815 );

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // In array
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
                $translated = __( 'İletişim Bilgileri', $domain );
            }
        }
    }

    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext',  'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```

---

- To check for virtual products you could use

```php
function filter_gettext( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    if( $text == 'Your order' && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // Is virtual
            if ( $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) {
                $translated = __( 'İletişim Bilgileri', $domain );
            }
        }
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext',  'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```