# how can i change woocommerce billing information text for virtual product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I'm using [How can I change “Your order” text on checkout page in WooCommerce under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63179762/11987538) and need to change this code for multiple product id or just for virtual products ? how can i do it ?

Comment: I have updated my original answer, this question can be removed

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I change "Your order" text on checkout page in WooCommerce under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179429/how-can-i-change-your-order-text-on-checkout-page-in-woocommerce-under-certain)